# Difference between rexp and qexp in R

Tags: r, exponential-distribution, quantiles

I need to write a simulation that requires the use of exponential distribution. I was wondering what is the difference between the following two approaches in drawing random numbers from an exponential distribution?

```
qexp(p=runif(1),rate)

rexp(1, rate)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference is that rexp(1, rate) is just a little easier.

It's also almost twice as fast, but it's unlikely that the simulation of exponential samples would be slowest part of your simulation, so there's not much point in worrying about that.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a comparison between both implementations (which have exactly the same degree of validity):

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(x=qexp(p=runif(1e5),rate=2.3))
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
    x 7.704467 8.669387 13.04644 11.41903 13.79021 57.00468   100
> microbenchmark(x=rexp(1e5,rate=2.3))
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
    x 6.139942 7.356238 9.206156 8.243386 10.59891 17.29152   100
```

`rexp()` is thus slightly faster than the inverse cdf approach.